# Crear una consulta en Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

como puedo convertir esta consulta en eloquent (vaya que lo he intentado y recurro a preguntarle ya que no tengo idea)

```
select  id from solicitudes where id  not in (select autorizaciones.solicitud_id from autorizaciones)
```

Comment: Me parece mas facil que hicieras un procedimiento almacenado y lo llamaras, directamente que hacerlo con eloquent, 
¿por que no ensayas eso?

Answer (score 3):

Te puede valer esto:

```
DB::table('solicitudes')
    ->select('id')
    ->whereNotIn('id', DB::table('autorizaciones')->pluck('id'))
    ->get();
```

Con modelos:

```
Solicitud::select('id')
        ->whereNotIn('id', Autorizacion::pluck('id'))
        ->get();
```